# Strange background colour to text container in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, text, background

I have made a simple image slideshow with text underneath that changes with the relevant image. This seems to work fine on all browsers except IE8, the text seems to get a strange gray background color applied to the text, though it has no background color or any background image applied to it.

The html and css are as below:

HTML:

```
 <div id="slideshowContainer">
   <div class="slideshow"> 
      <img src="images/01.png" width="800" height="560" /> 
      <img src="images/02.png" width="800" height="560" />                         
   </div>

   <div class="info">
       <h5> This is text 1 </h5>
       <h5> This is text 2 </h5>
   </div>

   <ul id="nav">
       <li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
       <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
   </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.info {
list-style-type:none; z-index:150;  top:100px;  left:40px; width:300px;   height:200px;  }
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
      $('.slideshow').cycle({fx: 'fade',    pause: 1,  prev: '#prev',   next: '#next'});
        $('.info').cycle({fx:'fade', speed:  10 , prev: '#prev', next: '#next'});
        $('.info').cycle({cleartypeNoBg: true});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be cleartype.

See how jCycle fixed it [here](https://drupal.org/node/443598).